# Facebook App "Page Tab" Integration

Tags: facebook, tabs

Facebook is doing away with an "App" page for each that is created and replacing it with the ability to create a community page (by choice).

When adding a "Page Tab" I would previously go to the app page and click Add on the left side and the app would appear in my pages application profile.

Now that the app page is not being created I can't add the app to my page. I have tried the URL string with adding the app but keep getting an error.

Any ideas on how to add a "Page Tab" app to a page since the lastest update?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this link,
add your app_id and app_namespace,

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOURAPPID&next=https://apps.facebook.com/YOURAPPNAME/">Tab Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just spent 2 hours going through the same issue.
Here's how it was resolved:

```
http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=**&pages=1
```

Replace ** with your app ID, and a page will appear asking
you where you would like to have the app added.

Source:
http://dollsent.jp/wordpress/?p=10225